# I try to install cosmos on my localhost

Tags: fiware, filab

Now I try to install cosmos, but 1 error ecountered,

https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide on the step 3 i created 3 files, 2 .pem and 1 .cer, on the step 4 mv .pem /etc/pki/tls/certs cd /etc/pki/tls/certs

which is the .pem that i have to move?

Answer (score 0):

The `<ca_cert>.pem` in step 4 refers to the CA certificate.
I assume that you created a self-signed CA certificate, so it should be the `certnew.cer` file.